# Can't change month using ASP.NET globalisation

Tags: asp.net, .net, globalization

I am learning Asp.Net globalisation and localisation, and I found [this example](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/globalization.html).

The example is working fine, but when I change the month in the calendar, the calendar text is automatically changing to English.

I tried it with

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="language_Drp_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:Calendar>
```

But I am still having a problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you found is not a very good one. The correct place to set the culture in ASP.NET is to override the method `InitializeCulture`. I normally implement that method in a common base class for all my web forms.

You could implement something like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Session["locale"] != null)
    {
        string selectedLanguage = Session["locale"];

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Somewhere you have to store the selected language in the Session variable, e.g. like this:

```
Session["locale"] = langDropdown.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Then please mark it as the correct answer, so that other users can see.

Comment: Inside Page_Load give the two lines so that this function works fine      Session["locale"]=language_Drp.SelectedValue;          InitializeCulture();

Comment: For your purpose, that probably works fine. However it might be a bit dangerous to call InitializeCulture yourself. I would recommend to reload the page, as other places in your framework might initialize controls with language dependant resources before Page_Load is called. So after changing the language you could call Response.Redirect() to your page.

Comment: If am having a label displaying currency.How can i display it with respect to the language selected.I have used CultureInfo currency=new CultureInfo(selectedLanaguage); But I don't know to proceed further.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to display the currency according to the selected language, I never understood why this function even exists. Why would you change the currency when somebody changes the language from en-US to de-DE? You have to change the value as well. If you really need it you can format your string using "C", e.g. string.Format("{0:C}", money);

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a problem of postback treatment. HTTP connections are by nature stateless.

---

Sorry for the previous response, it was just a test. I´ve just recalled the postback issue.

By using slfan´s code and changing the drop box event interception method to:

```
protected void language_Drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["locale"] = this.language_Drp.SelectedValue;
    InitializeCulture();
}
```

It seems to work fine, keeping the selected culture even when selecting a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the example is correct. This

```
protected void language_Drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(this.language_Drp.SelectedValue);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(this.language_Drp.SelectedValue);
Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

should be changed to this

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (this.language_Drp.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        UICulture = this.language_Drp.SelectedValue ;
        Culture = this.language_Drp.SelectedValue ;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

This code came from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I haven't tested it and may require some tweaking but it should  at least get you on your way.

Comment: I have used already session object in order to store the login id,to display the user details.But i could not figure out how it is applicable in this case.Can you please help me.

Comment: @Newto.net Sorry I changed my answer, on second glance I realised the you needed to override the initializeCulture method. See my updated answer.

Comment: I can understand this code.But what happening actually is the function is executed when the page is getting loaded so SelectedValue is throwing an null reference exception.

Comment: @Newto.net Have you looked at the link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? You should be able to modify the code there to include the calendar control like in the example you're using. You can also just replace the listbox with the dropdown control.